# MSP430 assembly language: variable allocation error

Tags: assembly, msp430, code-composer

Learning MSP430 Launchpad assembly language in class. The current assignment is to do stepwise multiplication and division (i.e. simulating them with recursive addition and subtraction).

I went over how to declare variables in assembly language with the professor, but the attempt threw errors when I tried to compile.

```
; Initialization Operations
Init:
            mov.b   m, R4   ;store m in R4
            mov.b   M, R5   ;store M in R5
            mov.w   #0, R6  ;store 0 in R6

for:
            add.w   R4, R6  ;add contents of R4 to P
            dec.w   R5      ;decrement R5
            jnz     for     ;jump to R4 until R5 is zero
exitFor:
            mov.w   R6, P   ;store R6 in P
            jmp     exitFor ;infinite loop
            nop             ; end program

; Variables for multiplication
            .data
m:          .byte   #40     ; multiplicand
M:          .byte   #5      ; multiplier
P:          .short          ; product
```

The errors are all below the `.data` directive. The m and M lines threw `[E0200] Bad term in expression` and `[E0000] Commas must separate directive elements`, and the P line threw `[E0005] Operand missing`. I'm having similar problems with the division version of the program.

Comment: Note that assembly is assembled, not compiled.  The error is that you have a leading `#` sign.  This is wrong for directives.  Directives do not have addressing modes and just take their arguments without decoration, e.g. `.byte 40`.  For the `.short` directive, you forgot to give an initial value.  Add that and it should work.

Comment: ^Well that worked. Added as answer.

Comment: Cool!  Thanks for doing the writeup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comment by [Fuz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417501/fuz):

> Note that assembly is assembled, not compiled. The error is that you have a leading `#` sign. This is wrong for directives. Directives do not have addressing modes and just take their arguments without decoration, e.g. `.byte 40`. For the `.short` directive, you forgot to give an initial value. Add that and it should work. ([src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77238879/msp430-assembly-language-variable-allocation-error#comment136168782_77238879))

Well, that did it.

```
            .data
m:          .byte   40      ; multiplicand
M:          .byte   5       ; multiplier
P:          .short  0       ; product
```

Also I didn't originally initialize P because the lab instructions said to define but not initialize it. I didn't understand I needed to use `.space` or `.bss` to handle that, so strictly speaking the "correct" solution should be:

```
            .data
m:          .byte   40      ; multiplicand
M:          .byte   5       ; multiplier
P:          .space  2       ; product
```